# Initializing issue when using Slick.js

Tags: jquery, html, slick.js

I'm trying to initialize slick.js function in my webpage and I followed the instructions on http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and copied the "center mode" function as my Jquery function. But I didn't get any arrows/buttons and nav-docs generated in my slide show.

Here's my jsFiddle:

> https://jsfiddle.net/woodmanhu/cL0yuaze/

Here's code:

```
<div class="your-class">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
  </div>

 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.your-class').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
    });
```

CDN I used:

//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js

//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js

//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css

//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick-theme.css

Anyone can help me where I missed or I did wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.  I usually include jquery through the fiddle UI, but since you were importing it, it should have still worked (I think).

One of the other problems was that you had it set to show 3 slides, but only included 3 slides in the content (so there was nothing else to show).  I also set a max width on the container to make the scrollable area easier to demo.  The next/prev buttons don't show up very well, but that has something to do with the theme you're using.

Either way, here's an updated fiddle with your demo working.

edit: I added a blue background so you can see the next/prev buttons -- this is something you'll have to change in the template.  If you want to see the dots below the image, then you'll need to set the `dots` property to true.

https://jsfiddle.net/cL0yuaze/5/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.your-class').slick({
    dots: true,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '60px',
    slidesToShow: 3,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    }, {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
.container
{
  width: 500px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

body
{
  background: #3498db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='container'>
  <div class="your-class">
    <div>your content1</div>
    <div>your content2</div>
    <div>your content3</div>
    <div>your content4</div>
    <div>your content5</div>
    <div>your content6</div>
    <div>your content7</div>
    <div>your content8</div>
    <div>your content9</div>
    <div>your content10</div>
    <div>your content11</div>
    <div>your content12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This did solved the half of my question. But those left/right arrows and bottom docs should be auto-generated once I declared  `$("#id").slick();` right? I just don't know how I can call these items out.

Comment: If you want the dots to show, you need to enable them.  I updated my answer to include this option

Comment: @QIWENHU Take a look at http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and click settings to view all the out-of-box settings you can use.